# In async function why do I have to await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Say I have method such as this:

```
private async Task SomeMethod()
{
  await DoSomethingAsync();
  await DoSomethingElseAsync();
  return;
}
```

Given that `DoSomethingElseAsync` returns a `Task` it would seem like you should be able to do this:

```
private async Task SomeMethod()
{
  await DoSomethingAsync();
  return DoSomethingElseAsync();
}
```

but the compiler complains about this:

> Since '`SomeMethod`' is an async method that returns '`Task`', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return '`Task<T>`'?

Why is that?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it's not an exact duplicate of *this* question. The OP isn't asking when to use await. This asks `why can't I return a Task?`

Comment: @YvetteColomb This is not duplicate, the question you are referring is when to use await and this one is asking why second method cannot simply return instead of writing await, I think english is very clear to identify both as different.

Comment: Before the first `await DoSomethingAsync();` is completed - method has already returned to its caller (it's asynchronous method after all). So there is no way you can return specific value after that `await` - caller already received a return value at this point and moved forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its pretty much like how `yield return` and `return` works. for an iterator you have either of these methods

```
public IEnumerable<int> SomeIterator()
{
    for(int I = 0; I < 10; I++) yield return I;
}

public IEnumerable<int> SomeIterator()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 10); // return result of another iterator.
}
```

but you cant have both. it doesn't work, because an iterator is either converted to a class by compiler to handle lazy iteration with `yield`, or its just like other normal methods that returns something else.

```
public IEnumerable<int> SomeIterator() // not valid
{
    for(int I = 0; I < 10; I++) yield return I;
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 10); 
}
```

The story is same about `return` and `async/await`. for method that has return type of `Task` you either return `Task` or use `async/await`.

for `Task<T>` if you use await you must return `T` but you can not return `Task<T>` because the method is compiled into state machine, then method must return `T`. (for `Task` method is void)

if you don't use `async/await` method will be exactly like other normal methods.

Comment: This, in combination with Evk's comment makes a lot of sense.
I still find it somewhat dissapointing though that `await Thing1(); await Thing2(); return` and `await Thing1(); return Thing2();` don't simply compile down to the same code under the hood, since it still makes logical sense (at least in my head!)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `await` - control flow might leave current method and return back to the caller. Suppose `DoSomethingAsync` is some long running operation. You call `SomeMethod`. `DoSomethingAsync` task is started but then you cannot wait for it to complete inside that method - otherwise nothing will be "async". So control flow leaves `Method` and should provide a return value to the caller. Return value is a task which completes when whole `SomeMethod` is completed. It can complete with or without result (`Task` or `Task<T>` return value). For that reason what you return after `await` could not be return type of `SomeMethod` - it can only be result type `T` (if `SomeMethod` returns Task) or just simple `return` to indicate completion of `SomeMethod` if it returns simple `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal method, `return` means "return this value, if any, from the method". In an `async` method, the meaning of `return` is changed to "set the result of the returned `Task` to this value, if any".

But you can't combine the two: in an `async Task` method, you can't directly `return` a `Task`. One reason for this is that if you `await`ed, the method actually already returned a `Task` and it can't return another one.

When it comes to returning, `async Task` method behaves like a `void` method, in that it only allows `return;`, but never `return value;`.